# Trouble Getting Database Connection to Work

Tags: php, sql

I'm building a website for an "Assassin" game, and currently I'm setting up the sign-up for the website. I'm just learning server-side setup, and I seem to be having trouble adding the individuals' credentials to the SQL database using "register.php". When I run the site, the register.php page simply doesn't appear. Could you help me fix my code for register.php? Thank you!

```
<?php 
require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php"); 
require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");
include("Includes/header.php"); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, key, iv_size, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    function RandomString($length)
    {
        $characters = ’0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’;
        $randstring = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randstring = $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
        }
        return $randstring;
    }
    $code = RandomString(25);
    mail($email, "Your code for the Assassin game.", "Your code is: $code");
    $salt = RandomString(8);
    $hashedcode = "";
    for($i=0;$i<5;i++){
        $hashedcode = sha1($hashedcode.$code.$salt);
    }

    $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $encryptedname = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $name, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encryptedemail = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $email, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encryptedname_base64 = base64_encode($encryptedname);
    $encryptedemail_base64 = base64_encode($encryptedemail);

    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('ssssssi', $encryptedname_base64, $hashedcode, $encryptedemail_base64, $key, $iv_size, $salt);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();

    $creationWasSuccessful = $statement->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
    if ($creationWasSuccessful)
    {
        $userId = $statement->insert_id;

        $addToUserRoleQuery = "INSERT INTO users_in_roles (user_id, role_id) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $addUserToUserRoleStatement = $databaseConnection->prepare($addToUserRoleQuery);

        $userRoleId = 2;
        $addUserToUserRoleStatement->bind_param('dd', $userId, $userRoleId);
        $addUserToUserRoleStatement->execute();
        $addUserToUserRoleStatement->close();

        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userId;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed registration";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semi colon at the end of the following line:

```
mail($email, "Your code for the Assassin game.", "Your code is: $code")//here
```

Comment: Turn on the error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: The problem is, I can't get it to report an error because it simply gives me a white blank page for http://localhost:55018/register.php. I can't view the errors in my code through error reporting

Comment: start working through your code by putting 'var_dump($variable_name)' in it, one at a time and moving it. OR. Use 'die('i am here '.__FILE__.__LINE__)'. starting from the top! It is what i use when i get a 'blank page'. It works! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and do that to try to find where it went wrong!

Comment: fyi, PHP parses the full script before it runs it. so you can put all your functions, classes etc at the end of the the script with a 'return' or 'exit' statement before them. Makes the code look cleaner, see the structure more clearly and is easier to maintain.